# libcusolver.so.8.0 : can not open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, importerror

I have installed nvidia-381, cuda 8.0 and CuDNN 6.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

Comment: What steps did you follow during your install, so far it seems you're missing a shared library, this kind of errors tend to point toward an incomplete installation of pre required components

Comment: 1. Cuda (but nvcc --version is not giving anything) 2. CuDNN 6.0

Comment: when i run "sudo apt-get install cuda" it says, cuda is already the newest version. but nvcc --version says command is not recognised

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64